# TP-LINK Archer T2UH wifi fastroaming on Linux slow or sometimes cannot connect on AP

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

we are running this on Linaro Ubuntu on ARM. We are using a TP-LINK 
Archer T2UH USB dongle attached to the ARM board connected to a 5Ghz-only 
network with 6 to 9 APs configured to share the same SSID. It sometimes 
takes several minutes to be able to reconnect to another AP and we also 
note that it doesn't always pick the closest AP with the strongest signal 
strength. The dongle also seems to have some hardware support for roaming 
(Fastroaming?), but the Linux driver has that disabled. The same dongle 
seems to work a lot better when plugged into a Windows laptop. 
We are using wpa_supplicant, because NetworkManager seems to be 
incompatible with it.
We have configured the wpa_supplicant to use bgscan of "simple:10:-70:30".

Wondering if any of you guys have experience dealing with wifi drivers on 
Linux and this TP-LINK in particular?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Realtek wifi AP at home, in an ARM too not with Linaro but with Armbian. I will be and soon buying another chipset. I also deal with wifi at work, Meru and Cisco.

The experience being an  wifi AP in Linux has been catastrophic. As an wifi client, only slightly better. Bugs in the chipset, bugs in the default firmware of Debian, bugs in Linux in several wifi drivers, packages from the manufactures  that are mostly old versions of the firmware that need an outdated hostapd that brings backs old bugs already fixed.

Often most of the wifi problems are also due to noise. If you manage to eliminate part of this noise, so much the better. From what you talk about delays, you seem to be in a pretty crowded place.

The basic recommendations for dealing with noise are simply:
- if you have a dual 2.4GHz and 5GHz chipset, try shutting down the 2.4GHz;
- if you are not able or do not want to go without 2.4GHz, at the very least, enable only 802.11g, and be done without the 802.11b.

As for they not getting always the correct AP, that is a fairly irritating quirk in the wireless design. Either you have logic dealing with that at the AP/controller side (Meru controller tries to hand them over to the nearest AP for instance) or you use different SSIDs, which may help or may worsen the situation depending on your needs (for mobile users it may make people stay longer with the weakest AP).